# Mobile automation testing

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, sendkeys

I am trying to test mobile application login page. i am using selenium for script on IntelliJ and appium for inspection. i am trying to sendkeys to email field its not getting input. the code i am using for sending keys

driver.findElement(By.id("textinput_placeholder")).sendKeys("Hello@gmail.com") ;

input field is being selected but it does not send any keys while mobile keyboard popup. i tried to select the input field before sending keys still no luck. i tried to find element by xpath by id by class